# what's the best way to do age verification?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm curious if there's a "best practices" approach to doing age verification.  I was thinking I would grab the milliseconds from right now and the milliseconds from their birthdate and then see if their birthdate + ageReq * (365 * millPerYear) > currentMillisecond.

I believe this will work, but am wondering if there's either anything faulty with this approach and/or if there's a library that tackles whatever pitfalls I may not be anticipating here (for example, is there a leap year problem?)

This problem is language agnostic, I'm currently in Java, but am curious what the right way to do this would be irrespective of language.

TIA

Comment: Are you assuming the user can't change their clock or implement a proxy to edit the date returned by a web service call?

Comment: This may be what you need
http://user.xmission.com/~goodhill/dates/deltaDates.html

Comment: Your idea is good, the only flaw is the "current time" part. It's a pretty bad idea to use the clock system because the user could change its value. It would be better to check it against a server or another PC which has the clock value you have configured

Comment: Sounds like a good idea until you realize that there's no such constant as `millPerYear` - leap seconds, leap days make that a bit more interesting. Really, use a library for it, don't badly reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, I'm assuming nothing :) I'm asking what the best way to handle this is. As it happens, for the app I'm building, changing the date is not something the user can actually do (it's a kiosk app in a locked down android tablet where the user can't get to the settings). But your point is well taken! thanks.

Comment: In some other thread on stackoverflow someone commented that you could just do `entered date should be smaller than today - 18 years` (or 21, or whatever)... which works perfectly and is a lot easier to implement than milliseconds and datediffs etcetera

Comment: @Phortuin, following your comment I went and looked at the Calendar class again and lo and behold there's an add method that totally does what you're suggesting! How the heck did I miss that before?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). And yes there is slight flaw in your check. This is not very accurate. Depending upon, how much legal compliance you have to follow, you can either live with it or not. Joda time is a good library as it does take care of all basic checks.

If you are looking for language agnostic. Then you can look into the code of Joda-time. as it precisely calculates the dates.

Comment: this looks like it will be exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an existing birthdate then use the Date and Calendar classes to get an accurate difference. If you use your method then it isnt exact because of leap years / seconds etc... Dates are a mess to work out by hand.

If you dont currently have a birthdate and you dont need to record it I would advise against your application actually asking for one, because its annoying as hell, and when I have to do it I just scroll down the years and pick a random one older than 20 or so. Just ask yes or no if you are over/under X.

Comment: Exactly this. Most websites have no legitimate need to know my birthday, so they get "1 January, 1900".

Comment: sadly this is a client requirement. I wholeheartedly agree with you, however.

Comment: Rest assured your client will be getting fake information from me if I ever deal with them. :P